# Is code clone a common practice in C,Java and Python?

Tags: programming-languages, duplicates, language-design, code-duplication

Code clones, also known as [Duplicate code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_code) is often considered harmful to the system quality.

1. I'm wondering whether these duplicate code could be seen in standard APIs or other mature tools.
2. If it is indeed the case, then which language(such like C,Java,Python,common lisp etc.) do you think should introduce `code clone` practice with a higher probability?

Comment: maybe i'm dense but I'm having a hard time figuring out what exactly you're asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: @chesles Thanks for your advice and I have changed a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code cloning is extremely common no matter what programming language is used, yes, even in C, Python and Java.

People do it because it makes them efficient in the short term; they're doing code reuse.   Its arguably bad, because it causes group inefficiencies in the long term: clones reuse code bugs and assumptions, and when those are discovered and need to be fixed, all the code clones need to be fixed, and the programmer doing the fixing doesn't know where the clones are, or even if there are any.

I don't think clones are bad, because of the code reuse effect. I think what is bad is not managing them.

To help with the latter problem, I build [clone detectors (see our CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/CloneDR)) that automatically find exact and near-miss duplicated code, using the structure of the programming language to guide the search.  CloneDR works for a wide variety of programming languages (including OP's set).

In any software system of 100K SLOC or more, at least 10% of the code is cloned. (OK, OK, Sun's JDK is built by an exceptionally good team, they have only about 9.5%).  It tends to be worse in older conventional applications; I suspect because the programmers clone more code out of self defense.
(I have seen applications in which the clones comprise 50%+ of code, yes, those programs tend be awful for many reasons, not just cloning).

You can see clone reports at the link for applications in several langauges, look at the statistics, and see what the clones look like.

Answer (score 3):

All code is the same, regardless of who writes it.  Any API that you cite was written by human beings, who made decisions along the way.  I haven't seen the perfect API yet - all of them get to redo things in hindsight.

Cloning code flies in the face of DRY, so of course it's recommended that you not do it.  It's harmful because more code means more bugs, and duplication means you'll have to remember to fix them in all the clones.

But every rule has its exceptions.  I'm sure everyone can think of a circumstance in which they did something that "best practices" and dogma would say they shouldn't, but they did it anyway.  Time and other constraints don't always allow you to be perfect.

Suggesting that permission needs to be granted to allow such a thing is ludicrous to me.  Be as DRY as you can.  If you end up violating it, understand why you did it and remember to go back and fix it if you get a chance.

Comment: +1 for realizing that sometimes you need to go against the guidelines and that you should make sure you know WHY you went against those guidelines when you do so. I will note, however, that sometimes you shouldn't "go back and fix it" because the reasons going against the guidelines is a constant (ie, you choose to duplicate the same code twice in a tight loop because pulling it out into a method would introduce overhead and you KNOW (measured) that the tight loop in question is a performance issue already).